# JAVA update database on JTable cell change

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, updates

He I am noob to Java (Thats not new) and I can't find a good tutorial for this. I use jTable to display a table filled with data from a MySQL database.

So far so good, I get the table:

[image: table preview]

Standard you can click a table cell and it changes to a text-field with can be filled with something new. You all know that, but how can I use this to also update the value in my database?

My code:

```
import [...];
public class table extends JPanel {
    public String table;
    private Database db;

    public table(String tablename, Database db){

        try {
            table = tablename;
            this.db = db;

            //Get table with and height
            ResultSet res = db.query("SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `"+table+"`");
            ResultSet res2 = db.query("SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '"+table+"'");

            int rows = 0;
            int collums = 0;

            res.next();
            res2.next();

            rows = res.getInt(1);
            collums = res2.getInt(1);

            //Get table column names and set then in array
            ResultSet clom = db.query("DESCRIBE  `"+table+"`");

            String[] columnNames = new String[collums];

            int s = 0;

            while(clom.next()){
                columnNames[s] = clom.getString(1);
                s++;
            }

            //get table data and put in array
            Object[][] data = new Object[rows][collums];

            ResultSet result = db.query("SELECT * FROM `"+table+"`");

            int q = 0;

            while(result.next()){
                for(int a=0; a<= (collums - 1); a++){
                    data[q][a] = result.getString(a + 1);
                    //System.out.println(q + " - " + a);
                }
                q++;
            }

            //Make Jtable of the db result form the two array's
            final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            // do some event listening for cell change

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("table editor");
            scrollPane.setOpaque(true);
            frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(600, 800);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I need to bind some kind of table listener and when something changes I take all the values of the table and update them with a query.

How can I do this?

This is my pseudo code:

```
table.bindCellEventListner(callback(t){
     Array row = t.getAllValuesAsArrayOfRow();

     String data = "";

     int f = 0
     while(row.next()){
         data .= "`"+clom[f]+"` = '"+row[f]+"',"
         f++;
     }
     data.delLastChar();
     db.query("UPDATE `"+table+"` SET "+data+" WHERE `id` ="+row[0]+";");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

A deleted answer plagiarised Rachel Swailes' answer from 14 years ago, found [here](https://coderanch.com/t/338715/java/Update-database-editing-cells-JTable). For completeness and because the answer **is** correct and useful, I have quoted the relevant text here:

> Step 1: It's going to be way easier for the whole thing if you make your table extend a TableModel from now (if you haven't already). So if you need help with that just ask.
>
> Step 2: In the table model you need to enable the cells to be editable. In the TableModel class that you make, you need to add these methods

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { 
  return true; 
}

public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
  rowData[row][col] = value;
  fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

> Step 3: You will see in the second method that we fire a method called fireTableCellUpdated. So here we can catch what the use it changing. You need to add a TableModelListener to your table to catch this.

```
mytable.getModel().addTableModelListener(yourClass);
```

> And in the class that you decide will implement the TableModelListener you need this

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
  int row = e.getFirstRow();
  int column = e.getColumn();
  TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
  Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
  ...
}
```

> now you have the data in the cell and the place in the grid where the
>
> cell is so you can use the data as you want