# JTable simple code when a row is selected?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

I have a JTable and I populated the table by using Vector objects. I want the database (that gives the data to my jtable) to be updated after a change is made to the jtable. I thought a special mode for updating. I want to do the update with an other method. This method receives an argument. I want to give the value of the first column (it's a code of the table in database, so it's an integer)  of the row selected by the user in the JTable.
Can anyone give me an example code to do that? I don't know how take the "value of the first column of the row selected by the user in the JTable".
I read that i have to create a costum tablemodel and override some methods, but which methods and how to implement that methos to achieve my objective? Thanks.

My code is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class provemain2 {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new provemain2();
        }
    });
}

private final JButton button;
private final JTable table;
private final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

public provemain2() throws HeadlessException {

    JFrame one =new JFrame();

    one.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    one.setVisible(true);

    table = new JTable(tableModel);
    one.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    button = new JButton("Load Data");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    loadData();
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    });
    one.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    one.setSize(640, 480);
}

private void loadData() {
    //LOG.info("START loadData method");

    button.setEnabled(false);

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root","psw");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Acquirenti");
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // Names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        }

        // Data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(i));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }

        tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in Load Data", e);
    }
    button.setEnabled(true);

    //LOG.info("END loadData method");
}

}
```

Comment: See [*How to Write a Table Model Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html), as shown in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17232118/230513).

Comment: You can write your own [table model][1] and save your data into the database when the method setValueAt(...) is called


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is to load all data in row into a new form(update form) or exiting form Then when form appear it will load selected row data, form with update button
User can update any field and you should run update statement using id